# Querying null in JSONField is different between Django 3.2 and 4.0

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Let's say I have a Django model with a `JSONField`:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField()
```

And I create the following objects:

```
event1 = Event.objects.create(data={"key": None})
event2 = Event.objects.create(data={"key": "null"})
```

In Django 3.2.13, the following queries return some results:

```
Event.objects.filter(data__key=Value("null"))
# [event1]

Event.objects.filter(data__key="null")
# [event2]
```

In Django 4.0.5, the same queries return different results:

```
Event.objects.filter(data__key=Value("null"))
# [event1, event2]

Event.objects.filter(data__key="null")
# [event1, event2]
```

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield) aren't clear which results are correct. I would lean towards the v3 results.

Any idea which one is correct? Is this a bug in v4? I filed a ticket in the Django bug tracker here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33820#ticket

Comment: Are you using SQLite?

Comment: Yes, I’m using SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in Django. See the ticket for more information: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33820#ticket